# In Azure Data Studio, queries are all disconnected

Tags: azure-data-studio

I am trying to move from SSMS to Azure Data Studio, primarily to take advantage of the easy git integration.  In Azure Data Studio, all my queries (the .sql files) all show up; everything works as expected.  It was easy to add github integration.  But unlike SSMS, each query is disconnected at start.  I've saved the collection of files as a workspace.  The Server I want is shown as an active connection in the server list.  Is there a way to default the queries to be connected at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible for the moment. There is already a similar issue in the GitHub repo to have a default connection for files in a folder/workspace. You can find it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/6171).

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly the issue described by the git hub issue.  I voted it up there.